# in vgg16 ssd model, the feature maps from Conv5 and Conv7 are not directly used for prediction. Is my understanding correct?

Tags: computer-vision

the following ssd architecture comes from the original [paper](https://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Ecyfu/pubs/ssd.pdf) with 2 arrows i added.

[image]

the layer pointed out by the red arrow labelled "Conv4_3", followed by Conv6, and then Conv7. Conv4, Conv7 and the layers after Conv7 are fed to the layer pointed out by the blue arrow, which means Conv5 and Conv7 are not directly used for prediction. Is my understanding correct?

what is the layer pointed out by the blue arrow called? the detector layer?